# filter and change a column in pig

Tags: filter, foreach, replace, apache-pig

suppose my data looks like

```
row1 cats val12 val13
row2 dogs val22 val23
row3 cats val32 val33
...

data = load 'file' AS (row:chararry, pets:charray, val2:charray, val3:charray);
```

filter data to only save 'cats' rows

```
felines = filter data by (pets matches 'cats');
```

now change 'cats' to 'lions'

```
lions = foreach felines generate replace (pets, 'cats', 'lions');
dump lions;

(lions)
(lions)
...
```

my goal is to create new rows to add to my table

```
newFelines = foreach lions generate rows, lions, val1, val2;
                                    Error ^^^^^
"Error during parsing. Scalars can be only used with projections"
```

how can I obtain a set with the following new rows?

```
row1 lions val11 val12
row3 lions val31 val32
```

TIA,

Answer (score 3):

Line by line:

There is no 'chararry' or 'charray' data type:

```
data = load 'file' USING  PigStorage(' ')  AS 
    (row:chararray, pets:chararray, val2:chararray, val3:chararray);
```

Extracting 'cats':

```
felines = filter data by (pets matches 'cats');
```

Replacing 'cats' with 'lions' can be done like that:

```
lions = foreach felines generate row, REPLACE(pets, 'cats', 'lions'), val2, val3;
```

or like that:

```
lions = foreach felines generate row, 'lions', val2, val3;
```

Comment: In this case, you don't need to `FILTER` ahead of time for `lions = foreach felines generate row, REPLACE(pets, 'cats', 'lions'), val2, val3;`, it should just be `lions = FOREACH data GENERATE row, REPLACE(pets, 'cats', 'lions'), val2, val3;`